# Start a thread inside a cpp file of a header file in C++ <process.h>

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a `class A` with a function`void runThread()`  to call new thread. This is my `A.cpp` with `struct SendInfo` and function `void thread(...)` are not included in header file `A.h`:

```
//A.cpp
struct SendInfo{
   int a;
   std::string mess;
   SendInfo(int _a, std::string _mess){
      a = _a;
      mess = _mess;
   }
};

void thread(SendInfo* args){
   std::cout << args->mess << std::endl; // Result here is nothing :-?
}

void A::runThread(){
   SendInfo info(10,"dump_string");
   std::cout << info.mess << std::endl; // Result here is "dump_string"
   _beginthread((void(*)(void*))thread, 0, &info);
}
```

When in main function, i call `runThread()` of `A object`, the result of `info.mess` is good, but `args->mess` have no string. So what's my problem? and how to solve it?

Comment: SendInfo is allocated on the stack, but you send a pointer into _beginthread, immediately after which the stack is unwound one level. Typo or fatal bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the local variable `info`; as soon as `runThread` exits, this variable goes out of scope and you must no longer access it, even from the other thread.

You need to ensure `info` has a lifetime which extends until the end of your `thread` function (or at least, until you've accessed it for the last time in `thread`).

Answer (score 0):

What Phillip Kendall said and, additionally, be wary of thead-safety when you make the change - don't just globalise `info`, encapsulate it in `A`.